# No sound from audio set in BMW7 (E38)

Tags: bmw, audio

My 95' BMW E38 recently broke down its audio system. I can't hear anything from radio or CD set. It is difficult to find the cause. I even tried connecting only amplifier and radio module (no luck). Things I have eliminated already:

- Speakers are ok
- Fuse in radio tuner located in the trunk is ok
- Other fuses are ok too
- Radio module is ok

My car has 4:3 TV and cassette slot in the front panel. Tuner, amplifier, CD changer, GPS, TV module and GPS module are located in the trunk.

Comment: Is this the factory radio setup that is installed in your car?

Comment: Yes it is. I think it's the amplifier, but I'm not 100% sure. A used one costs around 100$ so I want to be sure i really need one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the amplifier. All the other modules produced the correct signal. I exchanged the amplifier to a friend's device from E39, it worked.

Comment: Good to know they are compatible.  I notice the part numbers are different - did you notice any differences/issues when you tried an E39 amp?

Comment: No. It worked ok.